# How can I use a COUNT(DISTINCT var) to return the count of unique values per group?

Tags: sql, t-sql, group-by, count, distinct

I need to return a count of unique values, but unique *per group* of the result set, not unique to the entire result set. For example I would like the following code:

```
SELECT col1 AS letters, count(DISTINCT col2) AS numbers
GROUP BY col1;
```

applied to this data:

```
col1    col2
a        5
a        5
a        6
b        1
b        2
b        6
```

To return this:

```
col1    col2
a        2
b        3
```

If the above code will not produce this, how can I accomplish this is T-SQL?

Comment: Add a `GROUP BY col1` expression to your query. This is SQL 101. Find a good book or tutorial in order to learn the basics of SQL before you try to go any further - it will save you a lot of frustration.

Comment: I forgot to add the group by clause. I wasn't sure if using distinct this inside the aggregate made it distinct per group or distinct among the entire result set.

Comment: The code you've posted after your edit will do what you ask. Are you even making **an attempt** to execute the code to try and solve this yourself? Running your SELECT on the sample data you've posted would tell you if it was correct or not, and you might actually learn something in the process instead of having to depend on us to hold your hand.

Comment: Your query has no `FROM` clause, you need to select from a table.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this works for your solution, you need to use group by on col2 with count distinct of col2

```
SELECT
    col1,
    COUNT(DISTINCT col2)
FROM
    count_unique_values_per_group
GROUP BY
    col1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT col1
               ,dense_rank() over (partition by col1 order by col2 asc) + dense_rank() over (partition by col1 order by col2 desc) - 1
FROM my_table
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply concat function to get the unique count. Hope this helps..

```
SELECT col1, count(distinct col1 + col2) FROM table_name group by col1;
```

or

```
SELECT col1, count(distinct concat(col1,col2)) FROM table_name group by col1;
```